# Motion and Measurement Models for Turtlebot 2

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, xtion, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am looking for the motion and measurement probabilistic models for the Turtlebot 2. I cannot seem to find anything online about them. I'd like to implement a basic EKF using the Turtlebot 2 so I would need these models in order to get started on that project. Where would I find these models or is there a reasonable way (not needing to know the Kobuki and Xtion internal code) to find the models myself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229065/motion-and-measurement-models-for-turtlebot-2/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Relevant discussion over in the [kobuki mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/yujinrobot.com/forum/#!msg/kobuki-users/TE8_rhPqXCI/3omDiYQ5BAAJ).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0